Troubleshooting Git autocrlf Issues Across Windows and Ubuntu
I’m working on my project from two machines, one running Windows and the other Ubuntu.
On both machines, I’ve set up the following configuration in Git:
git config core.autocrlf false
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git config --system core.autocrlf false
git config --local core.autocrlf false

However, when I run git status on Windows, Git marks all my files as modified, even though I haven’t made any changes.
It seems that none of these configurations are fixing the issue. Could you help me resolve this?
git version on windows : 2.47.0.windows.1
git version on ubuntu : 2.43.0
Thank you!

Given it's 2024 now, and every text-editor on Windows handles \n style newlines just fine - let me ask you: do you actually need autocrlf? - I realized that I don't, so I disable autocrlf entirely: it causes more problems than it solves.

...also, check your .gitattributes file, which has the eol option for setting LF-vs-CRLF on a per-file/extension basis.

Sorry I forgot to put false in the main post.
my .gitattributes file contain : * text=auto

Have you looked at a diff of the changes? Maybe the files contain windows file endings now - in that case you could simply try git checkout .

I was so sure the problem was with EOL that I didn't even look at what git diff was saying:
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
which is actually a change in the file permissions.
After running:
git config core.fileMode false
I no longer see the differences.
Thank you!

I was so sure the problem was with EOL that I didn't even look at what git diff was saying:
old mode 100755
new mode 100644

which is actually a change in the file permissions.
After running:
git config core.fileMode false

I no longer see the differences.
Thank you!

Glad you found the problem
